# Post method does not run for large image sizes (using Flask, Nginx, Gunicorn, Google Cloud VM Instance)

Tags: nginx, flask, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, gunicorn

I am building a web app online that uses a deep learning image classifier built with keras. I am using nginx and gunicorn along with a Google Cloud VM Instance to deploy, and flask to build the web app itself. The web app deploys fine, and runs perfectly for small images, however when I input a large image it just loads forever, and does not ever enter the POST method.

When I deploy the app locally, it works perfectly with any image size, so I am sensing that this has to do with nginx and/or gunicorn.

I tried changing the max_body_size in the nginx config file to be much bigger than what I need as such:

```
server {
client_max_body_size 40M;
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
}
```

However, this doesn't fix the problem. Does anyone know what could be the problem? Could it have anything to do with the system I chose for my Google Cloud platform VM? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH set to? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/ What is the timeout value for gunicorn? Do you see anything additional in the browser debugger?

Comment: Is there layer between your app and the internet? I mean, do you have load balancer or stuff like this? What is the size of your image?